# Can Jitterbit (or any ETL tool) do field-by-field "insert null values" without using the bulk API?

Tags: null, jitterbit, etl

I can see that when an ETL tool is using the Bulk API, there isn't a global "insert null values" setting and you have to explicitly set cells to `#N/A` to get them to overwrite to null.

That's nice, because in my situation, I am using the tool to data-load tabular data where I will want to distinguish, cell-by-cell, between these two meanings:

- "I have nothing new to add -- whatever is already in Salesforce is fine"
- "Please actually clear out this value in Salesforce"

The question is, am I stuck using the Bulk API if I want to use an ETL tool that simply offers an operation-wide "INSERT null values" checkbox on "non-bulk" data loads?

It [looks like](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007HM8) perhaps tools could be built to have "field whitelists" where any `null`s should be automatically interpreted as "please actually clear out this value in Salesforce" on a field-by-field basis *(which in this case is granular enough for me ... for certain fields, the data being loaded will always be the "source of truth" so universal load-nulls for those fields is acceptable)*, but I don't see a UI in my tools *(particularly Jitterbit)* to actually take advantage of that.

Am I likely stuck refactoring my standard UPSERT in a 3rd-party ETL tool into 2 separate operations (one for the "insert nulls checked" columns, one for the rest) / refactoring it into a bulk operation *(unfortunately, Jitterbit doesn't just let you toggle a "use bulk" switch, so that doesn't sound fun either)*?